How can I avoid making all my rust code async for one dependency?
So I've created a library (let's call it libA) using that uses reqwest under the hood to call a REST API and I've added many functions for each of the endpoints. Because I just needed something simple, I used the blocking feature of reqwest to make all the calls synchronous which was great as the users can use normal rust code. There are multiple binaries which now use this library.
However I now have a new binary which actually wants to run async and this causes libA to throw with this error:

Cannot drop a runtime in a context where blocking is not allowed. This happens when a runtime is dropped from within an asynchronous context.

This seems to be caused by having nested runtimes, the one that the user has created, and the one that reqwest/blocking creates.
It seems like I have two possible paths forward:

Have the new client use block_in_place or something equivalent for every call into libA. Testing this does work but leads to very messy code as everything ends up wrapped, Results are hard to handle, and things seem to require being copied?
Change libA to be async by default, and change all the original binaries to async as well? This would be a lot of work and then all those simple binaries would turn into async "fun".

Neither option seems particularly appealing, is there another option I'm missing? Is there a recommended way to this? Am I just being dumb?

According to the reqwest docs you linked, the expected way to handle this is to have the new client use spawn_blocking: If the immediate context is only synchronous, but a transitive caller is async, consider changing that caller to use tokio::task::spawn_blocking around the calls that need to block.

spawn_blocking is a possible solution for this. Results don't need to be copied, and the usage is relatively straightforward.
struct Foo(i32);  // Doesn't implement Copy

fn some_sync_function() -> Result<Foo> {
    Ok(Foo(42))
}

async fn get_foo() -> Result<i32> {
    let foo = spawn_blocking(some_sync_function).await?;  // <- All you need
    Ok(foo?.0)
}

Note: spawn_blocking doesn't run the blocking function on the same threads where async tasks run. Instead, Tokio spawns a new dedicated thread for it, that's why blocking is allowed. More about that in the docs.
Playground

Thanks! That is basically what I have been doing with block_in_place which does effectively the same thing, but without spawning a new thread (avoids copying). I guess I was hoping for a way (or pattern) to avoid wrapping every call to libA with block_in_place or spawn_blocking. It is really annoying as it panics when you miss wrapping, but there isn't a lint or compiler error that shows you where the missed call actually is.
